# Pattern for JpaRepository use?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I"m just starting on JpaRepository and am wondering what patterns others use to handle it. I noticed that I wound up declaring at least 2 repositories in my dao layer.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

Customer findById(Integer id); 
Page<Customer> findByLastname(String name, Pageable pageable);

Page<Customer> findByLastnameLike(String name, Pageable pageable);

}


 public interface FilmRepository extends JpaRepository<Film, Long>

Page<Film> findByTitleLike(String name, Pageable pageable);

Page<Film> findByDescriptionLike(String name, Pageable pageable);

Film findById(Long id);

}
```

Would most people recommend / try and use separate controllers and service layers (1 for each interface) or combine as much as possible? I recognize that this question is highly application specific, but is there a general best practice in this regard when using the JpaRepository interface? I wound up combining them and frankly it looks a mess and I'm thinking of rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

When I write business layer I prefer to write one service that has actions with **common business logic**. That service can use multiple DAO (repository) classes, and combine them. Usually, in business service logic there is not only a need to access different database tables but using additional services (calling external web services, communicating with MQ, logging service, security services, etc). From all this we can conclude that in single business layer class we must use multiple repository and/or other service classes.

Business layer should not only be interface for accessing repository, business layer should do some business logic while interacting with repository.

If you have a code that looks messy to you, maybe you should try to refactor it, but I doubt that you will have much benefit if you isolate all business services and controllers.

But as you said, every approach is highly application specific. But, in general if you write CRUD applications one business class per repository is good approach, but if you have complex business logic I'm afraid that is not possible.

For example you can define

```
@RestResource(path = "customer", rel="customer")
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {

Customer findById(Integer id);

Page<Customer> findByLastname(String name, Pageable pageable);

Page<Customer> findByLastnameLike(String name, Pageable pageable);

}
```

and get crud REST service without creating business layer logic by using spring-data-rest (note: this is just an example).

Same thing stays for controllers.